# How to show all items with retrieve having parameters in PowerBuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

If dw.retrieve does not have parameters,I can use dw.retrieve() to get all items in datawindow.
But  if retrieve has parameters, how can I get all iterms using dw.retrieve()?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

What you can do is define the DataWindow without parameters and then use the SetSQLSelect DataWindow method to modify the SQL when you need to limit the data returned.

Or you could create two DataWindow objects that are identical except for the parameters and reassign them to the control at runtime depending on which one is desired. You will need to call SetTransObject after the change. The DataWindow control has a property DataObject which is the name of the DataWindow object. Change that and the call SetTransObject.